# gitosis clone submodule .git directory missing

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitosis

When cloning submodules from a gitosis repo, I got all files except for the .git directory. .git directory is missing. Instead, I got a single .git file. I use git submodule init and git submodule update to clone submodules. How can I get .git directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

submodules have their `.git` directory inside the `.git` directory of the enclosing repo. the `.git` file points there.